# JavaBridge - Probably php was not installed as "/usr/bin/php-cgi" or "c:/php/php-cgi.exe"

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I am trying to setup a JavaBridge between my Java-application and Apache/PHP application. First I tried through CLI =>

```
MacBook-Pro:php-java-bridge_5-2 username$ java -classpath JavaBridge.war TestInstallation
Starting a simple servlet engine: [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java, -jar, /Users/username/Downloads/php-java-bridge_5-2/ext/JavaBridge.jar, SERVLET_LOCAL:8081]
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : VM                  : 1.8.0_92@http://java.oracle.com/
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : VMBridge version             : 5.2.2    
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : logFile             : 
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : default logLevel    : 3
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : socket              : SERVLET_LOCAL:8081
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : java.ext.dirs       : /Users/username/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : php.java.bridge.base: /Users/username
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : thread pool size    : 20
Sep 03 12:32:34 VMBridge INFO : JavaBridgeRunner started on port INET_LOCAL:8081
Invoking php: [php-cgi, -n, -d, allow_url_include=On, /Users/username/Downloads/php-java-bridge_5-2/test.php]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not run PHP ([php-cgi, -n, -d, allow_url_include=On, /Users/username/Downloads/php-java-bridge_5-2/test.php]), please check if php-cgi is in the path.
```

This seemed without success so I tried another option; I installed TomCat with Apache Mamp. The installation went well and I deployed the JavaBridge.

Unfortunately when trying to accessing it, I receive a similar error as when I was trying to run it throughout the CLI.

```
HTTP Status 500 - An IO exception occured. Probably php was not installed as "/usr/bin/php-cgi" or "c:/php/php-cgi.exe"

type Exception report

message An IO exception occured. Probably php was not installed as "/usr/bin/php-cgi" or "c:/php/php-cgi.exe"

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: An IO exception occured. Probably php was not installed as "/usr/bin/php-cgi" or "c:/php/php-cgi.exe"
 or "/Applications/MAMP/tomcat/webapps/JavaBridge/WEB-INF/cgi/php-cgi-x86_64-mac[.sh]|[.exe]".
Please see "php_exec" in your WEB-INF/web.xml and WEB-INF/cgi/README for details.
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIServlet.handle(PhpCGIServlet.java:366)
    php.java.servlet.CGIServlet.doGet(CGIServlet.java:469)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "php-cgi" (in directory "/Users/user"): error=2, No such file or directory
    java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    php.java.bridge.Util$Process.start(Util.java:839)
    php.java.bridge.Util$ProcessWithErrorHandler.start(Util.java:937)
    php.java.bridge.Util$ProcessWithErrorHandler.start(Util.java:991)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIServlet$CGIRunner.execute(PhpCGIServlet.java:271)
    php.java.servlet.CGIServlet.handle(CGIServlet.java:400)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIServlet.handle(PhpCGIServlet.java:355)
    php.java.servlet.CGIServlet.doGet(CGIServlet.java:469)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

At the moment I am out of inspiration of solving this problem, any advice?

Comment: Well, where _is_ your PHP binary? And what is it called?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, it is located at /usr/bin/php . Should this point to the binary in my MAMP directory? I tried solving it with sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php /usr/bin/php but I got Operation not permitted.

Comment: How did you install PHP?

Comment: I am just using the standard version; PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2016 19:16:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies + the version from MAMP (7.0.10) . Should I make any changes here?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by installing php-cgi. Thank you very much for thinking with me @Chris.

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. Consider [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and accepting your answer. This shows other users that you found a solution.